# How should I manage fact insertion in drools to avoid a memory leak?

Tags: java, drools

I am using Drools 7.8.0 to manage real time data ( 10000 facts every 5 seconds).
I am inserting them in the working memory using :

```
KieSession kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();
EntryPoint entryPoint = kieSession.getEntryPoint("myData"); 

new Thread( new Runnable() {
                      @Override
                      public void run() {
                          kieSession.fireUntilHalt();
                      }
                    } ).start();

while ( true )
{
Data data = recieveData();
factHandle=entryPoint.insert(data);
}
```

However, this is causing a memory leak :

**`64,994 instances of "org.drools.core.common.EventFactHandle", loaded by "jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader @ 0x702500000" occupy 113,316,792 (71.06%) bytes. These instances are referenced from one instance of "java.lang.Thread", loaded by "<system class loader>"`**

so I tried keeping track of my facts and using **update** instead of insert but this affected the rule's behavior and some facts weren't matched.

```
 Map<String,FactHandle> allfacts = new HashMap<String,FactHandle>();

if( !allfacts.containsKey(dataName) && data!=null)
            {
                factHandle=entryPoint.insert(data);
                allfacts.put(dataName,factHandle);
                
            }
            else
            {
                
                entryPoint.update(allfacts.get(dataName), opcTagData);
                
            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //error 
        }
```

Here's an example of the rules I have:

```
declare Data
    @role( event )
    @timestamp( timestamp )  
    @expires( 20s )   
      
end

rule "status not available for 10 seconds "
dialect "java"

when
    d: Data(Name.contains("/Smart/Status")) from entry-point "myData"
    eval(!d.getValue().equals("Available"))
    not(
    Data(
      this.getName() == d.getName(),
      this.getValue().equals("Available"),
      this after[0s,10s] d) from entry-point "myData")
    
    
then
    doSmthg();

end
```

I can't figure out what's the right way to to insert the facts and still get the expected result without facing a memory leak

PS:
I'm using fireUntilHalt because I used Temporal Operators when writing the rules and I noticed that using fireallrules does not give me the expected result.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. You've got an unmanaged thread (bad), a `while(true)` (bad), and calling `update` causes Drools to reevaluate _all_ rules so it's making an awful situation even worse.

Comment: Im trying to evaluate real time data using drools. First I fire the rules then I insert the data into the working memory .. the only reason I'm using update is because when I used insert, I got a memory leak problem .. I'm not sure what's the proper way to do this which is why I posted this in the first place.

Comment: Drools will try to retract to detect when to retract your events based on the `@expires` metadata and the rules where the events are used, but there is no guarantee of that. Try to get rid of that `eval` you have in there (you can write that constrain in the pattern above) and see if that helps. If not, you will have to come up with your own eviction strategy.

Comment: In addition to what Esteban said, you're inserting facts via a while-true loop. This is going to do an insertion every few milliseconds -- you're quickly going to overwhelm your system. The usual pattern is to have a separate thread on a timer that inserts a fact every X seconds (where X is something reasonable.) If the while-true _is_ correctly simulating your real-world data requirements, then the system you're running on simply doesn't have sufficient resources to handle the processing.

Answer (score 2):

I tested your rule and retraction works for me. Each event was retracted in 20s.
Can you confirm you use `stream` [mode](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.43.1.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#cep-modes-con_decision-engine)?

Set stream mode using system property

```
drools.eventProcessingMode=stream
```

Set stream mode using Java client API

```
import org.kie.api.conf.EventProcessingOption;
import org.kie.api.KieBaseConfiguration;
import org.kie.api.KieServices.Factory;

KieBaseConfiguration config = KieServices.Factory.get().newKieBaseConfiguration();

config.setOption(EventProcessingOption.STREAM);
```

Set stream mode using project kmodule.xml file

```
<kmodule>
  ...
  <kbase name="KBase2" default="false" eventProcessingMode="stream" packages="org.domain.pkg2, org.domain.pkg3" includes="KBase1">
    ...
  </kbase>
  ...
</kmodule>
```

---

It happened in previous versions of drools that explicit event retraction worked better

```
rule "retract expired events"
salience 1
duration 20000
when
    d: Data() from entry-point "myData"
then
    retract(d);
end
```

---

This is how I tested your code

test.drl

```
package draft;
dialect "java"

declare Data
    @role(event)
    @timestamp(timestamp)
    @expires(20s)
end

rule "retract expired events"
salience 1
duration 20000
when
    d: Data() from entry-point "test it"
then
    retract(d);
end

rule "status not available for 10 seconds"
when
    d: Data(Name.contains("/Smart/Status")) from entry-point "myData"
    eval(!d.getValue().equals("Available"))
    not(
    Data(
        this.getName() == d.getName(),
        this.getValue().equals("Available"),
        this after[0s,10s] d) from entry-point "myData")
then
        System.out.println("alert");
end
```

PlaygroundTest.java

```
@DroolsSession("test.drl")
public class PlaygroundTest {
    
    @Rule
    public DroolsAssert drools = new DroolsAssert();
    
    @Test
    public void testIt() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            drools.insertAndFireAt("myData", new Data(new Date(SECONDS.toMillis(i * 5)), "/Smart/Status", "Unavailable"));
            drools.advanceTime(5, SECONDS);
            drools.printFacts();
        }
        drools.assertFactsCount(3);
        drools.advanceTime(5, SECONDS);
        drools.printFacts();
        drools.assertFactsCount(2);
        drools.advanceTime(5, SECONDS);
        drools.printFacts();
        drools.assertFactsCount(1);
        drools.advanceTime(5, SECONDS);
        drools.printFacts();
        drools.assertFactsCount(0);
    }
}
```

Data.java

```
public class Data {
    
    private Date timestamp;
    private String name;
    private String value;
    
    public Data(Date timestamp, String name, String value) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
    
    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

stdout

```
00:00:00 --> inserted: Data[timestamp=Thu Jan 01 02:00:00 EET 1970,name=/Smart/Status,value=Unavailable]
00:00:00 --> fireAllRules
00:00:05 Facts (1):
Data[timestamp=Thu Jan 01 02:00:00 EET 1970,name=/Smart/Status,value=Unavailable]
00:00:05 --> inserted: Data[timestamp=Thu Jan 01 02:00:05 EET 1970,name=/Smart/Status,value=Unavailable]
00:00:05 --> fireAllRules
00:00:10 <-- 'status not available for 10 seconds' has been activated by the tuple [Data]
alert
00:00:10 Facts (2):
Data[timestamp=Thu Jan 01 02:00:00 EET 1970,name=/Smart/Status,value=Unavailable]
Data[timestamp=Thu Jan 01 02:00:05 EET 1970,name=/Smart/Status,value=Unavailable]
00:00:10 --> inserted: Data[timestamp=Thu Jan 01 02:00:10 EET 1970,name=/Smart/Status,value=Unavailable]
00:00:10 --> fireAllRules
00:00:15 <-- 'status not available for 10 seconds' has been activated by the tuple [Data]
alert
00:00:15 Facts (3):
Data[timestamp=Thu Jan 01 02:00:00 EET 1970,name=/Smart/Status,value=Unavailable]
Data[timestamp=Thu Jan 01 02:00:05 EET 1970,name=/Smart/Status,value=Unavailable]
Data[timestamp=Thu Jan 01 02:00:10 EET 1970,name=/Smart/Status,value=Unavailable]
00:00:15 --> inserted: Data[timestamp=Thu Jan 01 02:00:15 EET 1970,name=/Smart/Status,value=Unavailable]
00:00:15 --> fireAllRules
00:00:20 <-- 'status not available for 10 seconds' has been activated by the tuple [Data]
alert
00:00:20 Facts (3):
Data[timestamp=Thu Jan 01 02:00:05 EET 1970,name=/Smart/Status,value=Unavailable]
Data[timestamp=Thu Jan 01 02:00:10 EET 1970,name=/Smart/Status,value=Unavailable]
Data[timestamp=Thu Jan 01 02:00:15 EET 1970,name=/Smart/Status,value=Unavailable]
00:00:20 --> inserted: Data[timestamp=Thu Jan 01 02:00:20 EET 1970,name=/Smart/Status,value=Unavailable]
00:00:20 --> fireAllRules
00:00:25 <-- 'status not available for 10 seconds' has been activated by the tuple [Data]
alert
00:00:25 Facts (3):
Data[timestamp=Thu Jan 01 02:00:10 EET 1970,name=/Smart/Status,value=Unavailable]
Data[timestamp=Thu Jan 01 02:00:15 EET 1970,name=/Smart/Status,value=Unavailable]
Data[timestamp=Thu Jan 01 02:00:20 EET 1970,name=/Smart/Status,value=Unavailable]
00:00:30 <-- 'status not available for 10 seconds' has been activated by the tuple [Data]
alert
00:00:30 Facts (2):
Data[timestamp=Thu Jan 01 02:00:15 EET 1970,name=/Smart/Status,value=Unavailable]
Data[timestamp=Thu Jan 01 02:00:20 EET 1970,name=/Smart/Status,value=Unavailable]
00:00:35 Facts (1):
Data[timestamp=Thu Jan 01 02:00:20 EET 1970,name=/Smart/Status,value=Unavailable]
00:00:40 Facts (0):
```

Comment: yes I am using stream mode as well. How is the retraction being tested ???

Comment: We had bad experience with `@expires` on the drools project about 5 years ago, we end-up with a dedicated rule which retracts events not to relay on drools inner 'retraction logic'. But latest documentation has clear statement that event 'should be retracted' when time argument was added. I was trying to add other rules to the session with bigger 'time intervals' to reproduce the issue with @expires, but I was not able to. When you explicitly retract events with the rule you have additional lifecycle callback which you don't have with @expires, but  overall it behaves exactly the same way

Comment: anyway I would advise to make an integration test with all rules you use in production, not to test single rule in isolation

Comment: Can you share your experience, did dedicated rule for retraction work better? Can you test your app with it?

Comment: I think likely the issue is how OP is inserting his facts. In your test you're inserting them 5 seconds apart. In the originally posted code OP has a tight while true. My guess is that his likely ran out of memory well before 20s was up.

Comment: Hi Roddy, yep, that idea was around in the comments, but he didn't change requirements so I worked with what was given (practical drools tasks is what inspire me now, I'm working on a dull project with the only technology I can learn (xml) for quite a time and try not to forget what I new). Also I I thought about count of facts 65k. If retraction works as expected he should be inserting more than 3 events per millisecond which I think is quite much for reading from JMS or something like this. This is really possible for parallel kafka consumers or something not that straightforward

Comment: Also we are talking about 'status' events, which I would say is enormous count for a day, not for 20 seconds. So my guess that either retraction doesn't work after 20 secs or most likely there are other events which pollute working memory, again 20 secs don't work for them. So my point was to prove that there is nothing wrong with the rule itself as of retracting facts. But we should make integration test with other rules (and maybe other flows which insert data).  Dumb issue with the drools processing mode was not confirmed